# Data Macro - MySql Backend

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I am wondering if anyone can provide any advice on how I go about the following:

I created a Microsoft access database for mobile numbers. This was compiled of a front end form and back end table, it also kept an audit through another sub form that I had embedded in the original front end form and all worked correctly.

However this database has since had all of its back end tables converted to mySQL.

I was previously able to use the After Insert and After Update options that where available in the Table tab, however these have become grayed out after the table migration.

Is there anywhere else I can add my code to still provide the relevant audit details?

Thanks

Comment: This is a very interesting problem. Unfortunately, my experience with Access is almost entirely SQL Server based. That being said, I think the problem is not truely related to MySQL, but rather Access being dumb. My thought here being that the tables might not be linking properly anymore, so it *may* help if you removed the back-end tables and readd them, and relink them to the front-end. My reasoning behind this, is Access shouldn't be graying out anything for those proceedures, they're (mostly) unrelated to the back-end tables. Unfortunately, this is a shot in the dark, hope it helps.

Comment: See my post below. Table events written for SQL server, oracle, or MySQL are all written their own way and in their own language. So you can only use those table event options if you have a Access back end - for Oracle, or MySQL or for whatever other system, then the store procedure code, and how you define table events (that call the store procedure code) are really so very different that Access can't know, or figure out how such code is to be written. I mean, you think the MySQL workbench is going to automatic write store procedure code and table triggers for Oracle or SQL server?

Comment: If MySQL does not support store procedures, then such code can't be moved. I am not sure what programming language is used for MySQL store procedures, but whatever the language choice the have is what the table event code and procedures must be re-written in.

Answer (score 1):

The table triggers in Access were introduced in 2010, and they are TRUE database engine level triggers, and true store procedure.

In other words, of course such table events are to be gray out when adopting MySQL, Oracle, SQL server etc.

Given that near EVERY vendor has their own way of declaring variables, declaring triggers, declaring and writing store procedure code then you have to re-write that table logic in the language of the database system you choose – not in Access anymore.

So Access since 2010 has table events, and store procedures. If you dump Access and use say SQL server, then obviously such store procedure code and triggers must be written in the back end language and system. So in the case of SQL server, then you use t-sql to create these store procedures and table events.

If you using Oracle, then you write such store procedure code in pl/sql.

And if you using MySQL, then you have to write and setup such procedures code in their store procedure language.

So keep in mind that for Access 2010 and later, you have not only the ability to define table triggers, but you ALSO have the ability to write store procedural code at the database engine level. These triggers and store procedure code EVEN run if you don’t install access on your computer, and say open the access database tables with say vb.net, c#, FoxPro etc. The “data macro” language is thus not VBA, and that code runs at the engine level independent of the front end.

So if you choosing to store the data in oracle, then such table event and store procedure code has to be written in oracles language and placed on the server.

And this “approach” to my knowledge is the same for every database system on the planet until such time that the SQL language is extended to support procedural code, and becomes a standard that all database vendors adopt.

So not only do vendors all tend to have different dialect of SQL (that is quite close), the store procedure languages for each vendor are significantly different – including the store procedure language used for Access tables and triggers.

So you have to move and re-write your Access "data macro" code in whatever language that MySQL allows such store procedure code to be written.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the table triggers to MySQL. (Prepare to learn MySQL)

Easiest way is to download and install MySQL Workbench (free) from MySQL.com. You can use the same credentials you've used to link the tables (assuming it has enough privileges). Otherwise you need to acquire login details from your IT department to allow you to edit tables.

Once you have Workbench and login details, seach in google "MySQL table triggers" there are many video tutorials which might help you.